# How to I get data from an observable to use in a different function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, observable

So, I happen to have a function as follows:

```
public getAssemblyTree(id: number) {

....

 const request = from(fetch(targetUrl.toString(), { headers: { 'responseType': 'json' }, method: 'GET' }));

        request.subscribe(
            (response) => {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    (this.parseAssemblyTree(data['flat_assembly_graph']));
                }
                )
            }
        )
```

```
public updateAssemblyTree(id: number) {
        let res = this.getAssemblyTree(id)
        this.asmTree.next(res);
    }
```

So, I basically need the data once the observable completes to be returned by the function to be stored in the variable res in the second function(public updateAssemblyTree(id: number) ). Can you guys please let me know on how to do that? I'm very new when it comes to using observables so writing the code down would really help me out. Thank you guy, for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that getAssemblyTree returns an observable or a promise, you can just subscribe to it as well. Thus:

```
this.getAssemblyTree(id).pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
.subscribe((response) => {
    if(response) {
        //set your method here.
    }
}).
```

the variable `this.componentDestroyed` is defined as `private componentDestroyed$ = new Subject<void>();`

Make sure to also discard of it in your component's `ngOnDestroy` as so:

```
this.componentDestroyed$.next();
this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
```

So what happens here is that your component will keep listening to and responding to changes in the `getAssesmblyTree` method as long as the component itself is not destroyed. This will only work though if the return type of the method is an Observable or a promise (if it is a promise just wrap it in a from).

Edit: May be overkill, but you could also look into using a store and this way you can subscribe to parts of the state. This way it pairs quite well with async pipes.